# Register a path via template layer, alt to hook_menu

Tags: drupal-7

Is there a way to register a path via template layer, like what hook_menu does via a module?

I can only work with isset($_GET['some_path']), but I am expecting more like a real registered path.

*some_path can be any special page which simply return/print 'print', 'unstyled content, 'xml' pages, etc.

Any hint would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i don't understand what u want exactly but if u want to implement hook_menu inside template file then..

im not sure about this but try to add the file name in the .info file like the following

files[] = my_template_file.tpl.php

then implement the hook inside your template file

dont forget to clear the cache